# Stored Procedure - Error in variable declaration and type

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AP_ModelingDataset_Creation1
    @Product varchar(max),
    @Segment varchar(max)
as
Begin
Declare @query2 nvarchar(max)

Declare @Responders_Count_query nvarchar(max)
Declare @NonResponders_Count_query nvarchar(max)
Declare @Percentage_query nvarchar(max)
Declare @Responders_Count int
Declare @NonResponders_Count int
Declare @Percentage float


--Oversampling:
set @Responders_Count_query = N'select @Responders_Count=count(*) from AP_'+replace(@Product,' ','_')+'_'+@Segment+'_ModelingDataset_Total where Flag=1'
set @NonResponders_Count_Query = N'select @NonResponders_Count = count(*) from AP_'+replace(@Product,' ','_')+'_'+@Segment+'_ModelingDataset_Total where Flag=0'
set @Percentage_Query = N'select @Percentage = ((@Responders_Count)*(10.0))/(@NonResponders_Count)'

set @query2 =
'SELECT s.*
into AP_'+replace(@Product,' ','_')+'_'+@Segment+'_ModelingDataset
FROM
(
SELECT *
from AP_'+replace(@Product,' ','_')+'_'+@Segment+'_ModelingDataset_Total
where Flag=1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM AP_'+replace(@Product,' ','_')+'_'+@Segment+'_ModelingDataset_Total
WHERE Flag=0 AND 
(SELECT '+@Percentage+') >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), [MSSalesTPID]) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
)s' 

EXEC sp_executesql @Responders_Count_query, N'@Responders_Count int OUTPUT', @Responders_Count OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_executesql @NonResponders_Count_query, N'@NonResponders_Count int OUTPUT', @NonResponders_Count OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_executesql @Percentage_query, N'@Percentage float OUTPUT', @Percentage OUTPUT;
exec(@query2)

END
GO
```

This stored procedure runs, but it throws an error

> Must declare scalar variable @responders_count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate `float` value to string

Change

```
(SELECT '+@Percentage+') >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), [MSSalesTPID]) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
)s'
```

to

```
(SELECT '+convert(varchar,@Percentage)+') >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), [MSSalesTPID]) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
)s'
```

Comment: Thank you.. I corrected that mistake.. But still it shows an error 'Must declare scalar variable @responders_count' Why does this happen when the variable is declared already?